# Как можно добавить цветной бордер к бейджу в табБаре?

Tags: swift, ios11

Каким образом можно добавить вот такой цветной ободок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

к бейджику для UITabBar (тени и "отблески" не нужны)

Comment: Как вы создаете сам значок?

Comment: сейчас использую стандартный таббаровский бейджик

Answer (score 1):

У стандартных значков сейчас нет таких свойств/методов меняющих borderWidth и borderColor https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem/1648567-badgecolor .

Конечно, можно пробежаться по subviews у ваших view и попробовать найти нужный вам значок, и у них уже поменять нужные вам свойства. Пример есть здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341603/is-it-possible-to-change-uitabbaritem-badge-color . Правда тут меняют цвет, но вы таким же способом можете заменить у layer borderWidth и borderColor.

Либо можете воспользоваться готовыми решения из https://github.com/Minitour/EasyNotificationBadge или https://github.com/evgenyneu/swift-badge.